# Grid Engine Queue Priority Setup

Tags: sungridengine

Son of Grid Engine - version SGE 8.1.9, CentOS 7.

We want to implement queues with job scheduling priorities, so a job to high priority queue are always schedule ahead of any other low priority queue.
Explanation:
3 queues:  High.q, Medium.q and Low.q
when jobs are queued, jobs in High.q needs to go first once resource is available, even they are submitted later. Medium.q jobs can go only if there are no High.q jobs pending. Same for Medium.q jobs scheduled ahead of Low.q.

We tried setting in each queues like:
for High.q:         seq_no                0
                    priority              0
for Medium.q:       seq_no                1
                    priority              5
for Low.q:          seq_no                2
                    priority              10

Our cluster is setup for:
queue_sort_method                 seqno
(we tried default "load" also)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at job reservations in SGE? `-R y` along side job priority might suffice for the purpose you seek